# Tweak code to copy sheet1 of a excel file to sheet1 new excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have the code to copy all the sheets from one excel file to another, but I only have one sheet and when it copies it paste the original as sheet1 (2) in to the destination file.

I need the code to not create a new sheet just past sheet1 into sheet1 of the destination file

I tryed playing with it but could not get it

Thanks

```
Sub CopySheets()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ASheet As Worksheet

'Turns off screenupdating and events:
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

 'Sets the variables:
 Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
 Set ASheet = ActiveSheet
 Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(WB.Path & "\MyOtherWorkbook.xls")  'Modify to match

'Copies each sheet of the SourceWB to the end of original wb:
For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    WS.Copy after:=WB.Sheets(WB.Sheets.Count)
Next WS

    SourceWB.Close savechanges:=False
    Set WS = Nothing
    Set SourceWB = Nothing

WB.Activate
ASheet.Select
    Set ASheet = Nothing
    Set WB = Nothing

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.The below code can fail if the source workbook is in excel 2010 (xlsx) and destination workbook is in excel 2003 (xls). You may also have a look at [RDBMerge Addin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm).

```
   Sub CopySheets()


    Dim SourceWB As Workbook, DestinWB As Workbook
    Dim SourceST As Worksheet
    Dim filePath As String

    'Turns off screenupdating and events:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    'path refers to your LimeSurvey workbook
    Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\LimeSurvey.xls")
    'set source sheet
    Set SourceST = SourceWB.Sheets("Management Suite Feedback - Tri")

    SourceST.Copy
    Set DestinWB = ActiveWorkbook
    filePath = CreateFolder

    DestinWB.SaveAs filePath
    DestinWB.Close
    Set DestinWB = Nothing

    Set SourceST = Nothing
    SourceWB.Close
    Set SourceWB = Nothing

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
Function CreateFolder() As String

    Dim fso As Object, MyFolder As String
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Reports"


    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    MyFolder = MyFolder & "\" & Format(Now(), "MMM_YYYY")

    If fso.FolderExists(MyFolder) = False Then
        fso.CreateFolder (MyFolder)
    End If

    CreateFolder = MyFolder & "\Data " & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY hh.mm.ss") & ".xls"
    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Hello Santosh, when I run your code the macro runs but no data is pasted (or maybe copied not shure which).  Also I am setting a path like this `Set SourceWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\RawData360.xls") 'Absolute Path`. would that maxe a difference? Thanks

Comment: @Tim i tested the code and its working for me. Can you try again & let me know if you are still getting issue. Is it possible to upload the file on skydrive ?

Comment: @Tim Absolute Path wont make any difference just make sure it exist at that link. Also it has a sheet with name as sheet1.

Comment: SORRY, I delete all the data in the original file with out knowing it so I thought the macro was not working. I get a error `Subscript out of range` Range is A to ER

Comment: @Tim Make sure sheet with name sheet1 exist. Can you let me know at which line.

Comment: In the original file (output from LimeSurvey) the sheet name is `Management Suite Feedback - Tri` I replaced `sheet1` with this and I am getting `Subscript out of range` I want the destination sheet to be `sheet1` I am `sorry` if I have been confusing and un-clear

Comment: @Tim The workbook from which you are running the code should have sheet name as "sheet1" or
 you may alter this line  `Set ASheet = WB.Sheets("Sheet1")` accordingly.

Source workbook for example "LimeSurvey" should have sheet "Management Suite Feedback"
or you may alter this line  `ASheet.Cells.Copy SourceWB.Sheets("Management Suite Feedback - Tri").Range("A1")`

Comment: Ok, I did as you said and checked 3x and ran the macro and what happens is all the data in the original file gets deleted!

Comment: @Tim your question says paste sheet1 into sheet1 of the destination file.  so it copies all cells of sheet1 and paste in destination sheet1. It deletes nothing.

Comment: Ok I know what the problem is, I can not believe how much I messed this up!! (My head hurts) everything is going in the wrong direction, I need to copy the original file in LimeSurvey with sheet name `Management Suite Feedback - Tri"` to a new and blank file `Blank` with sheet name `sheet1` I am running the macro from `Blank` . OH man could I have been more confusing!

Comment: @Tim i have updated the code. Please check & let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: That works very well Santosh, thank you!! for staying with me in all the confustion.