# Saving worksheet to PDF with automated filename

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the macro below so that the worksheet in use will print to PDF and the filename to be populated based on the contents of a specific cell.

It almost works but for some reason whenever I run it states that 'The output folder does not exist'.  This is because for some reason the file path is doubling up

(i.e.S:\Purchase Orders\2013\TEST - Damien\2013 Pos\S:\Purchase Orders\2013\TEST - Damien\2013 POs\filename.pdf

```
Sub SaveToPDF()


' This line of code calls your PDF printer and runs the conversion. Record your own macro to call your PDF printer and copy and paste it here.

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, ActivePrinter:= _
"Bullzip PDF Printer", Collate:=True

' This set of code tells the macro to pause for 2 seconds. This will allow for the PDF printer to run through its process and prompt you for a filename.

newHour = Hour(Now())
newMinute = Minute(Now())
newSecond = Second(Now()) + 2
waitTime = TimeSerial(newHour, newMinute, newSecond)
Application.Wait waitTime

' This line of code specifies your directory as well as the cell or range which you want the filename to come from.

FileName = "S:\Purchase Orders\2013\TEST - Damien\2013 POs\" & ActiveSheet.Range("BT12").Value

' This line of code sends the filename characters and the ENTER key to the active application (i.e. the prompt window). The "False" statement allows the macro to continue running without waiting for the keys to be processed.

SendKeys FileName & "{ENTER}", False

End Sub
```

If anyone could help me fix this code that'd be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the `CreateFolder` function from following link which will create unique file name and make sure your folder exist. You may have to tweak . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16386394/change-copy-sheet1-to-copy-workbook-in-macro/16386618#16386618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SendKeys "^(a)" & "{DELETE}" & Filename & "{ENTER}", False
```

it deletes old file name in print dialog box

ps: in my test it only worked when i set waitTime to 5 seconds, but may be i have slow machine

Comment: Shipormot - I copied and pasted your code and ran it and I got it to work second time round but Im finding that the file path (i.e. S:\Purchase Orders\2013\TEST - Damien\2013 POs) is being pasted in random spots in my worksheet. I take it you haven't come across this. Im not the most skilled at macros (only been attempting them the last 3 weeks) so any guidance would be great. Thanks

Comment: @Mortend, if answer solves problem in question please accept it. What about your second question, i recommend you post another question. But before think on its formulation, because it is unclear what you want to achieve. i think you need some logic to find cell with file name on sheet. Simpliest solution is to have fixed cell wich contains filename or cell coordinates which contains filename. But again it is unclear what you want at the end.

Answer (score 0):

See the [Bullzip examples](http://www.biopdf.com/guide/examples/microsoft_excel/)

```
Set settings = CreateObject("Bullzip.PdfSettings")
settings.SetValue "Output", fileName
settings.WriteSettings True
```