# Call sub not working the same as running macro by itself

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sub which works fine when run as a stand alone macro but if I call it

`Call selectFolderUpdateData`

it does not exacte this part

`selectedfolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled     Repository\")`

it gos directly to

`Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedfolder)`

```
Sub selectFolderUpdateData()
selectedfolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled     Repository\")
Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedfolder) 
End Sub
```

Thanks

`Edit`

Here is The whole thing

```
Sub selectFolderUpdateData()
Dim fso As Object
Dim selectedFolder$
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set selectedFolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360    Compiled Repository\")
Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedFolder)
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
.Title = "Select a Folder"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.InitialFileName = strPath
If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function


Function updateAllWorkbooks(WorkDir)
Dim fso, f, fc, fl
Dim newName As String, appStr As String, SubDir As String
On Error GoTo updateAllWorkbooks_Error
SubDir = workDir & "\" & "ConvertedFiles"
SubDir = WorkDir
If Not fExists(SubDir) Then
MkDir SubDir
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(WorkDir)
Set fc = f.Files
For Each fl In fc
If Right(fl, 5) = ".xlsx" Then
newName = Replace(fl, "xlsx", "xls")
newName = Replace(newName, WorkDir, SubDir)
If fExists(newName) Then
appStr = Format(Now, "hhmmss") & ".xls"
newName = Replace(newName, ".xls", appStr)
End If
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Workbooks.Open fileName:=fl
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=newName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8, _
    Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, _
    CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Function
updateAllWorkbooks_Error:
MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure      updateAllWorkbooks of Module Module2"
End Function

Function fExists(newName As String) As Boolean
Dim tester As Integer
On Error Resume Next
tester = GetAttr(newName)
Select Case Err.Number
Case Is = 0
    fExists = True
Case Else
    fExists = False
End Select
On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Then using the following to Call

```
Sub run()
    Call CopySheets
    Call selectFolderUpdateData
    Call Deletexlxs
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you also include the calling macro in the code excerpts ?

Comment: Hello Alexandre, see edit

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting a `Sub or Function Not Defined` type error on the `GetFolder`?

Comment: One suggestion (which probably won't fix the issue immediately), it's always best to properly dimension your variables.

Comment: You should probably not be using a function named `GetFolder` since that is a method already available to the FileSystemObject. Not sure if that would be causing some sort of irreconcilable conflict. Ultimately you need to determine whether you actually need to use FSO. I think you do not, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're simply working with string paths. To that end, I'm not sure why you're using the `GetFolder` method of FileSystemObject.

Instead, you can just use the string, like:

```
Sub selectFolderUpdateData()
Dim selectedFolder$

selectedfolder ="C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled Repository\"
Call TestToSeeIfThisWorks(selectedFolder)
Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedfolder) 

End Sub

Sub TestToSeeIfThisWorks(WorkDir as String)
msgBox workDir
End Sub
```

**Revision #1** This is working for me (not testing the `updateAllWorkbooks` yet.  Remove `Set` from the `Set selectedFolder`. This will error because `selectedFolder` is a string, not an object.

Also, you do not need a `FileSystemObject` in this subroutine (because you do not use it).

```
Sub selectFolderUpdateData()

Dim selectedFolder$

    selectedFolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\david_zemens\desktop\")
    'Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedFolder)
End Sub

Function GetFolder(strPath As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: David thanks for the response, I tried your solution, the meg box pops up with the directory but `selectedfolder` is still being ignored.  There is no error being thrown it is just not running. None of my other macros are acting this way.

Comment: Well if you're getting a msgBox, then `selectedfolder` is **not** being ignored.  Have you tried stepping through it with F8? You will notice an error with `Set selectedFolder`, because `selectedFolder is not an Object variable. Remove `Set` and see what happens?

Comment: David, I add your update and partial succsess. If I run `selectFolderUpdateData` by itself like `Sub AAA Call selectFolderUpdateData end Sub` then it runs as a "Call" but if I have `Sub AAA Call Macro1 Call selectFolderUpdateData end Sub` then it does not work

Comment: What happens when you **step through the code in debugger using F8**?

Comment: David, you solved the stated problem! Thank you. For some reason when I call `Sub AAA Call Macro1 Call selectFolderUpdateData end Sub` works for all Macro's except `CopySheets` ? which I got here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350356/tweak-code-to-copy-sheet1-of-a-excel-file-to-sheet1-new-excel-file from Santosh (works great) but for some reason interferes with `Call selectFolderUpdateData` but that is a different question. Thank you again.

Comment: `CopySheets` only interacts with very specific files and worksheets, make sure those exist. also, Santosh mentions that `The below code can fail if the source workbook is in excel 2010 (xlsx) and destination workbook is in excel 2003 (xls).`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using FileSystemObject you need to first create object of it.Your procedure will look like below.

```
Sub selectFolderUpdateData()
    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set selectedfolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled     Repository\")
    Call updateAllWorkbooks(selectedfolder)
End Sub
```

If the input parameter for `updateAllWorkbooks` is a Folder like in below code

```
Sub updateAllWorkbooks(fld As Folder)

End Sub
```

then use

```
Set selectedfolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled     Repository\")
```

else if input parameter for `updateAllWorkbooks` is a string like in below code

```
Sub updateAllWorkbooks(fld As String)


End Sub
```

then use

```
selectedfolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled     Repository\")
```

Comment: Hello Santosh, I update'ed my question  and put "updateAllWorkbooks" in it, neither solution worked in as "Call" though the 2nd worked as a stand alone Marco.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
Set selectedfolder = GetFolder("C:\Users\Tim\Desktop\SampleCo 360\360 macro\360 Compiled     Repository\")
```