# VBA Code to rename & save

Tags: vba, excel

I work in a sales office and currently we use hard copies of all sales quotes and file them alphabetically.  I have made an excel version of our quote paperwork to hopefully make everything more efficient.  Unfortunately we are not confident of everyone in the office's computer skills, so it needs to be made as user friendly as possible.

I need to use a command button through vba that will save the excel sheet to a specified path on our network & rename the copy as the cell content of a specified range of cells (if this is possible).

Basically for every quote I would like to have a saved copy of the sheet saved as "Doe.John.06.01.2013" if possible.  I did not know vba existed until yesterday, and while i think it is amazing and it made my inner nerd jump for joy, i am a code NOOB!...i have researched online and been unable to find anything like what I need.   If anyone on here can help me, i will be eternally grateful :)

Comment: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs <filename>

Comment: [Refer this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350356/tweak-code-to-copy-sheet1-of-a-excel-file-to-sheet1-new-excel-file/16350499#16350499)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you familiarize yourself with the Macro Recorder in Excel. Basically it allows you to record your actions into VBA.  It's a great way of learning what code to use to accomplish certain actions.  For example, I just recorded this:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Nemmy\Documents\Book2.xlsx", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

It's a fairly trivial matter to take that code and have it run on a button click.  You could modify it to get the file name from a couple of cell values using something like this:

```
    Dim sPath as string
    sPath=ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value & ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sPath, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
```

Cell A1 would contain your base path to your quote directory and Cell A2 would contain the name of the file.

Comment: holy crap i didn't know there was a recorder :) so happy i could kiss you right now!

Comment: so, i recorded the code to save as:
Sub SAVEQUOTE()
'
' SAVEQUOTE Macro
' SAVE QUOTE TO FOLDER
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'
    ChDir "C:\Users\Buckleys\Desktop\Deenas"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\Buckleys\Desktop\Deena's\Republic Services\NEW RESI SPREADSHEET.xlsm" _
        , FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub

which is awesome, but is there a way for me to have it pull the new file name from a range of cells in the worksheet?

Comment: I think my girlfriend might not like it if you kissed me :P Read the second part of post.  There's a line in there that constructs a file path and name from the values in two Excel cells.

Comment: Ok then...i don't want any girlfriends pulling my hair out ;) but thank you all the same...now that i know of this wonderful macro recorder and vba i see alot of nerding out in front of a screen in my future :)

Comment: Great.  The Macro Recorder is what got me out of the evil world of mechanical engineering and into programming back in the mid 1990's.  Best of luck :)

Comment: I don't mean to be a bother...but i get a compile error-expected expression on:
{
    sPath=ActiveSheet.Range('A1').Value & ActiveSheet.Range('A2').Value & ".xlsx"}

Comment: Double quotes should be used rather than single quotes.  I've fixed up the code in the answer.

Comment: @nemmy a word of warning: while the macro recorder is a great tool to start learning `VBA`, is does have a down side.  It's great for discovering features of the Excel object model (eg `SaveAs`!) but generaly produces very poor, inefficient code (eg full of `Select`s).  My advice: use it for what it's good for, but learn to code 'properly' too.

Comment: @chrisneilsen VBA produced by the Excel recorder is often the first experience a lot of people have with coding.  It's a good way of giving them an idea of what can be done and hopefully it opens up a wider world to them.  I think the shortcomings of the code it produces are far outweighed by the value it can give to new coders.  One only has to see the reaction of the OP to see the value it has.  But yes, the code it produces isn't great.